# Docker Container Not accessible after commit

Tags: docker

I just committed a docker container and getting following list

```
[root@kentuckianatradenew log]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
19d7479f4f66        newsslcyclos        "catalina.sh run"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8080/tcp   n2n33
88175386c0da        cyclos/db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 hours ago        Up 21 minutes       5432/tcp                       cyclos-db
```

But when I browse it through IP it won't accessible while same was fine before commit.

```
docker port 19d7479f4f66
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: docker logs -f 19d7479f4f66         and paste the logs

Comment: Consider including the command you used to commit the container, and how you're trying to find the committed container.  Note that committing a container creates an **image**, which may be used to create another container with the **image** as its starting point.

Comment: @ctt I have commited as  `docker commit container _id  tag name`

Comment: @ctt Then I did `docker run -d \
    --name=n2n33 \
    -p 80:80 \
    --net=cyclos-net \
    -e DB_HOST=cyclos-db \
    -e DB_NAME=cyclos \
    -e DB_USER=cyclos \
    -e DB_PASSWORD=cyclos \
    newsslcyclos`

Comment: @ctt `docker exec -it 19d7479f4f66 bin/bash`  open container in terminal